# Правильная ли это практика иметь перекрестные внешние ключи в двух различных таблицах?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть две таблицы  со связью один ко многим , хочу настроить внешние ключи сразу в двух таблицах ,

> в таблице users должно быть много post_id в таблице posts только один user_id.

Настораживает, то что в таблице users  будет много user_id  и *автоинкрементор* id больше не будет уникально показывать на user-а .

---

Используются ли вообще перекрестные внешние ключи, как быть тогда с уникальным id ?

Как  сделать правильно в этом случае ?

Отмечу что перекрестные внешние ключи нужны мне для Laravel отношений `belongsTo`,  `hasMany`.

Comment: Какие перекрестные внешние ключи? Какие уникальные ИД? Вы проблему на ровном месте создали. В таблице users ничего про posts не должно быть. В таблице posts должно быть поле `user_id`, __все__.

Comment: Покажите схему таблиц

Answer (score 1):

Вам нет необходимости делать перекрестные ключи. Как уже было отмечено достаточно поля `user_id` для таблицы **posts**. В модели **User** просто указываете связь `hasMany` и при необходимости имя внешнего ключа.